# Dynamic Button call JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a script and a Dinamic created Button and event OnClick doesn't work
I need to pass Id and inQuantidade to ValidarEstoqueVenda.htm and JavaScript is the only way i think its possible

```
page import="usuario.usuario"%>
<%@page import="DAO.DAO"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="produto.produto"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% usuario Usuario = (usuario) session.getAttribute("Usuario");%>
        <script>
            function clickVender(){
                var Id = document.getElementById('Id');
                var inQuantidade = document.getElementById('inQuantidade');
                if(Id.value != "")
        alert("You entered: " + Id.value)
                 else
        alert("Would you please enter some text?")
                document.location.href="ValidarEstoqueVenda.htm?Id="+Id.value+"&inQuantidade="+inQuantidade;
            }
        </script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.css">
<!-- Include CSS File Here -->
        <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
        <title>Estoque Online - Estoque</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav id="nav_f" class="default_color" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#" id="logo-container" class="brand-logo">Controle de Estoque</a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="Estoque.jsp">Estoque</a></li>
                <%if (Usuario.getTipo() == 2){%>
                <li><a href="CadastroEstoque.jsp">CadastroEstoque</a></li>
                <li><a href="CadastroTipo.jsp">Cadastro Tipo</a></li>
                <li><a href="Tipo.jsp">Tipo</a></li>
                <li><a href="Usuario.jsp">Usuario</a></li>
                <%}%>
                <li><a href="redirect.jsp">Sair</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
                <li><a href="Estoque.jsp">Estoque</a></li>
                <%if (Usuario.getTipo() == 2){%>
                <li><a href="CadastroTipo.jsp">Cadastro Tipo</a></li>
                <ul id='dropdown2' class='dropdown-content'>
                <li><a href="Usuario.jsp">Usuario</a></li>
                </ul>
                <%}%>
                <li><a href="redirect.jsp">Sair</a></li>
                </ul>
            <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
   </div>
        <form action="ValidarEstoque" method="get">
            <table class="striped responsive-table black-text teal darken-1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="id">Id</th>
                        <th data-field="nome">Descricao</th>
                        <th data-field="email">Quantidade</th>
                        <th data-field="Alterar">Alterar</th>
                        <th data-field="Excluir">Exlcuir</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <%  List<produto> produtos = new ArrayList<produto>();
                            DAO dao = new DAO();
                            produtos = dao.listarEstoque();%>                         
                            <%for(produto produto : produtos){%>
                            <td><%=produto.getId()%></td>
                            <td><%=produto.getDescricao()%></td> 
                            <td><input type="text" id="inQuantidade" name="inQuantidade" value="<%=produto.getQuantidade()%>"></td>
                            <% if(Usuario.getId() != 0){%>
                            <td><a href="CadastroEstoque.jsp?Id=<%=produto.getId()%>">Alterar</a></td>
                            <td><a href="Excluir.htm?Id=<%=produto.getId()%>&exclusao=Estoque">Excluir</a></td>
                            <td><a class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s12" onclick="clickVender()">Vender</a></td>
                            <%
                            }
                            %>
                        </tr>
                        <%
                        }
                        %>             
                    </tbody>
            </table>                                       
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The last tag  have the onCLick function.

Please Help me

Comment: minimal example please, error messages and something what you tried...

Comment: I don't find 'id=id'

Comment: there's no error message they simple do nothing

Comment: You usually have to refer to the DOM for that since the button was not there at first. In jQuery we use Document.ready or refer to the parent that was there before the button was.

Answer (score 0):

Your code don't have id named 'Id'.
and you should don't use inline event handler.

You should refer to my code.

[HTML]

```
<td>
  <input type="text" id="Id" name="MYID" value="my dummy Id">
</td>

<td>
  <input type="text" id="inQuantidade" name="inQuantidade" value="getQuantidade">
</td>

<td><a class="govender">Vender</a></td>
```

[JavaScript]

```
function clickVender() {
  var id = document.getElementById("Id");
  var inQuantidade = document.getElementById("inQuantidade");
  alert(id.value + ":" + inQuantidade.value);
}

document.querySelector(".govender").onclick = clickVender;
//or you can use addEventListener.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nigayo/n81hd5f3/

---

[# additional explanation]

you can see error messages on console tab of Chrome developer tools.
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console